# Configuration: Hiveserver2 & Beeline

Tags: hive

I am trying to connect Beeline with HiveServer2 and i am getting the below alert.

Need help to connect Beeline with HiveServer2.

[hdpsysuser@hdpmaster bin]$ beeline
which: no hbase in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/enter code here usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/hdpuser/.local/bin:/home/hdpuser/bin:/home/hdpsysuser/.local/bin:/home/hdpsysuser/bin:/usr/hadoopsw/hadoop-2.7.3/sbin:/usr/hadoopsw/hadoop-2.7.3/bin:/usr/hadoopsw/hive/bin:/usr/hadoopsw/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin/bin)
Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive
beeline> show tables;
No current connection

beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://hdpmaster:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://hdpmaster:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://hdpmaster:10000: hdpsysuser
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://hdpmaster:10000: **********
17/05/09 01:51:20 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to
  hdpmaster:10000
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
   jdbc:hive2://hdpmaster:10000: Failed to open new session:     java.lang.RuntimeException:
  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hdpsysuser is not allowed to impersonate hdpsysuser (state=08S01,code=0)

Comment: Looks like you are connecting as a system account, which is blacklisted for security reasons. Only standard users should run queries.

Answer (score 0):

add below property in hive-site.xml in hive conf

`<property>
 <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>`

Also if you want user ABC to impersonate all(*), add below properties to your 
core-site.xml

`<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.ABC.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>`

`<property>
 <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ABC.hosts</name>
 <value>*</value>
</property>`

Comment: I add the above property values, but unfortunately the error is there.

Comment: user your user name instead of ABC